# jQuery - If image width is less than 75px add 1/2 the difference as padding?

Tags: jquery

With jQuery how can I see if a div is less than 75px, and if it is add 1/2 (half) the difference as left padding?

So if an image is 75px or bigger, then nothing happens, but if it's 71px then 2px of left-padding is applied.

Note, the size is defined by CSS, the actual images are bigger.

Thanks

The following didn't work for me:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(function(){ 
        var img= $('#views_slideshow_singleframe_pager_product_slideshow-node_content_1 .pager-item img');
        if(img.width() <75)
        {
            img.css("padding-left", (img.width() -75)/2);
    });
});
```

UPDATE - I need to target several images on a page with this.

UPDATE - I'm adding the code suggestions locally so you cant see it live, but a non-js version of the site is here: [**link**](http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp-new/shop/bunny-pim-pink/pants)  - click on one of the thumbnails under the 'SIZE' drop down box to see a thumbnail that's too small. This version is a little out of date so I'll come back with a newer one as soon as its uploaded. Thanks

UPDATE - the thumbnail images are themselves generated by javascript, so the code needs to be run after they're created. I've used window load for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery, I'm not sure how bug-proof it is, though:

```
$('img').live('click', function() {
  $.each($('img'), function() {
    var image = $(this);

    if (image.width() < 75) {
      image.css('padding-left', ((75 - image.width()) / 2)); 
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT** : This code will fire each time **any** image is clicked. You can make this more specific by using a selector to find clicked images within a certain container, such as a "div".

I hope it helps, though,
spryno724

Comment: Your code is adding 38px of padding to all my images regardless (only one is less than 75px). My replacement of #imageID targets several images, could this be causing the problem? Thanks

Comment: Its creating too much padding and applying it to all the images targeted with the selector. Sorry if I should have mentioned, but I need to target multiple images on the page with the code, and they will have varying widths. Thanks

Comment: Hmm... then it is hard to say without _actually seeing_ the page. Try the edit above and see if it is any better.

Comment: Its creating too much padding but only applying it to the image that does require some padding. Im adding your code locally so you cant see it live, but a non-js version of the site is here: http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp-new/shop/bunny-pim-pink/pants click on one of the thumbnails under the 'SIZE' drop down box to see a thumbnail thats too small.

Comment: As much as I would like to help out, it is too difficult to help, since I cannot test it live. I would just keep in mind the jQuery width() method, and limit your selectors _only_ to the images you are trying to manipulate.

Comment: OK. Its not the cleanest solution but as the maximum number of thumbnails is 3 I could target each one individually with different code and see if that fixes things. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From your question I can't tell if you want to determine the div width or the image width so this should work for finding the width of anything (just change 'img' to whatever you want to add the padding to) and then adding the needed value to the left-padding.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $self = $(this).width();
    if($self < 75){
        var diff = (75 - $self) / 2;
        $(this).css("padding-left", diff);
    }
});
```

---

Update (the above would work for something like a div... but not an image):

In the browser I am using (webkit) the width of the image is not set when jQuery asks for it. This results in the width being 0 so the code takes 75, divides by 2 and then you get 37.5 added every time.

This should work (uses the image's onload event):

```
var the_width, the_diff;
    $('img').each(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        $("<img/>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function(){
            the_width = this.width;
            if(the_width < 75) {
                the_diff = (75 - the_width) / 2;
                img.css("padding-left", the_diff);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Its the width of the image. Your code is adding too much padding. It will take a while but I can upload the site so you can see what I mean. Thanks

Comment: @jdin - I see the problem. I'm updating my answer to explain.

Comment: Afraid it doesn't work. Im using the window.load function with the code, is that right?

Comment: @jdin - "I'm using the window.load function with the code, is that right?" No. Take what I have in the second chunk of code and stick it into a regular jQuery $(document).ready(function(){ my code in here }). No window.load